# Why is the compiler complaining about a possibly undefined property

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flex4, mxmlc, gumbo

I have a very simple practice program for Flex 4 ( Gumbo ).

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.ColorPicker;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.events.ColorPickerEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class testClass extends Sprite
    {
       private var cPicker:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();
       private var lbl:Label;

        public function testClass()
        {
            cPicker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,
                colorPicker_change);
            cPicker.move(10, 10);
            addChild(cPicker);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.text = cPicker.hexValue;
            lbl.move(10, 40);
            addChild(lbl);
        }

        private function colorPicker_change(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void
        {
            lbl.text = cPicker.hexValue; // ff0000
        }
    }
}
```

But after building with **'mxmlc.exe testClass.as'** on the command line, I get...

> > C:\src>mxmlc testClass.as Loading configuration file
> >     C:\flex_sdk_4\frameworks\flex-config.xml
> >     C:\src\testClass.as(21): col:
> >     32 Error: Access of possibly undefined
> >     pro perty hexValue through a reference
> >     with static type
> >     mx.controls:ColorPicker.
>
> ```
>         lbl.text = cPicker.hexValue;
>                            ^
> ```
>
> C:\src\testClass.as(28): col:
>   32 Error: Access of possibly undefined
>   pro perty hexValue through a reference
>   with static type
>   mx.controls:ColorPicker.
>
> ```
>         lbl.text = cPicker.hexValue; // ff0000
>                            ^
> ```

Why does it think that *cPicker* is static?  Or that *cPicker.hexValue* is undefined?

Also it seems that even after importing the ColorPicker library in the code using the *import* keyword, I somehow have to import it on the commandline for building as well.  Is that correct?

Comment: The "static" bit isn't saying that it's static - the *static type* (i.e. the compile-time type of `cPicker`) is `mx.controls:ColorPicker`

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  The error makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my reading of the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/langref/mx/controls/ColorPicker.html#propertySummary) `hexValue` isn't a property available on the ColorPicker.  Do you mean `selectedColor`?

Comment: Thanks, I was mixing Flex3 and Flex4.  The original example was done for Flex3.